# Asp.net web API Nlog implementation with UnhandledExceptionHandler

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api

I have an asp.net web api. I would like to log errors into a file. So I decided to use NLog. I already have UnhandledExceptionHandler so I added NLog as follows. I removed all the try/catch in order to log from a single point, just inside the handler.

Would you please have a look at my code? Is it good enough?

```
using System;
namespace Game.Handlers
{
    public class UnhandledExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
    {
        private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
        {
            var ex = context.Exception;

            string strLogText = FormatException(ex);

            var requestedURi = (string)context.Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
            var requestMethod = context.Request.Method.ToString();
            var timeUtc = DateTime.Now;

            SqlErrorLogging sqlErrorLogging = new SqlErrorLogging();
            ApiError apiError = new ApiError()
            {
                Message = strLogText,
                RequestUri = requestedURi,
                RequestMethod = requestMethod,
                TimeUtc = DateTime.Now
            };
            //sqlErrorLogging.InsertErrorLog(apiError);
            //NLOG
            logger.Error(strLogText + Environment.NewLine + DateTime.Now);
        }


        private string FormatException(Exception ex, int depth = 0)
        {
            var indent = "";
            if (depth > 0)
                indent.PadRight(depth * 4);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            IndentLine($"Source --- {ex.Source}");
            IndentLine($"StackTrace --- {ex.StackTrace}");
            IndentLine($"TargetSite --- {ex.TargetSite}");

            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                IndentLine("--- Inner Exception ---");
                sb.Append(FormatException(ex.InnerException, depth + 1));
                IndentLine("--- End Inner Exception ---");
            }
            if (ex.Message != null)
            {
                IndentLine($"Message --- {ex.Message}");
            }
            return sb.ToString();

            void IndentLine(string s)
            {
                sb.Append(indent);
                sb.AppendLine(s);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the sample NLog config:

```
<nlog xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/MyLogs/${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}-api.log" />
      <target name="eventlog" xsi:type="EventLog" layout="${message}" log="Application" source=" GamePIN Api Services" />
      <target name="database" type="Database" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Game; Initial Catalog=GameAPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;">
        <commandText> insert into ExceptionLog ([TimeStamp],[Level],Logger, [Message], UserId, Exception, StackTrace) values (@TimeStamp, @Level, @Logger, @Message, case when len(@UserID) = 0 then null else @UserId end, @Exception, @StackTrace); </commandText>
        <parameter name="@TimeStamp" layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@UserId" layout="${mdc:user_id}" />
        <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception}" />
        <parameter name="@StackTrace" layout="${stacktrace}" />
        <dbProvider>System.Data.SqlClient</dbProvider>
      </target>
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <!-- I am adding my 3 logging rules here -->
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="database" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="logfile" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="eventlog" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `ex` is not used anywhere else, so it can be in-lined.

```
string strLogText = FormatException(context.Exception);
```

The multiple calls to `DateTime.Now` will give different time stamps.

Hold on to the timestamp in one variable early in the function and reuse that.

It was already assigned here

```
 var timeUtc = DateTime.Now;
```

so use that

```
//...

ApiError apiError = new ApiError()
{
    Message = strLogText,
    RequestUri = requestedURi,
    RequestMethod = requestMethod,
    TimeUtc = timeUtc
};

//...
```

Given the variable name, the assumption is that the timestamp was meant to be UTC, which would mean that it should be using [`DateTime.UtcNow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=netframework-4.8)

The SQL error logging *(though commented out)* can be encapsulated into its own function/concern

```
private void LogSQL(string message, HttpRequestMessage request, DateTime timestamp) {
    var requestedURi = (string)request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
    var requestMethod = request.Method.ToString();
    SqlErrorLogging sqlErrorLogging = new SqlErrorLogging();
    ApiError apiError = new ApiError() {
        Message = message,
        RequestUri = requestedURi,
        RequestMethod = requestMethod,
        TimeUtc = timestamp
    };
    //sqlErrorLogging.InsertErrorLog(apiError);
}
```

This can be abstracted out into its own service/concern if so desired

The above and a few minor changes results in a refactoring of

```
public class UnhandledExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger {
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context) {
        DateTime timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string strLogText = FormatException(context.Exception);            
        //SQL
        SqlLog(strLogText, context.Request, timestamp);
        //NLOG
        NLog(logger, strLogText, timestamp);
    }

    private void NLog(Logger logger, string message, DateTime timestamp) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine(message);
        sb.AppendLine(timestamp);
        logger.Error(sb.ToString());
    }

    private void SqlLog(string message, HttpRequestMessage request, DateTime timestamp) {
        var requestedURi = (string)request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri;
        var requestMethod = request.Method.ToString();
        SqlErrorLogging sqlErrorLogging = new SqlErrorLogging();
        ApiError apiError = new ApiError() {
            Message = message,
            RequestUri = requestedURi,
            RequestMethod = requestMethod,
            TimeUtc = timestamp
        };
        //sqlErrorLogging.InsertErrorLog(apiError);
    }

    private string FormatException(Exception ex, int depth = 0) {
        //... omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Nkosi, I wonder if managing errors from a single point like UnhandledExcepitonHandler is a good idea? As a result I removed all try/catch block in the code.

Comment: I suggest reading up on cross cutting concerns.

Comment: Should I change timestamp to this `sb.AppendLine(timestamp.ToLongDateString());`

Comment: I think all the exceptions are not handled in UnhandledExceptionLogger. Would it be correct if I add logging also inside of GlobalExceptionHandler? What is your opinion?